# How do I create a gene simulator?

Tags: technology, genetics

I want a machine that can read DNA and then project what the creature looks like. I have a computer that is as powerful as needed but I don't know where to start.

What are there major challenges to simulating from a given sample? How might I get around these challenges?

You can't use an example database to simply tell what a strand means, like how you might be able to tell a person has red hair because people with red hair have this certain gene that gives them that color hair. It must be independently read and generated.

Comment: What do you mean by "independently"?

Comment: @Alexander It can read and decipher the DNA by itself rather than simply taking examples of certain parts of the gene code from a database. So if it depended on a database it might be able to guess how tall a person is or what their eye color or skin color is but if you gave it dog dna it wouldn't know what to do. Independently you could give it any example of DNA and be able to simulate what the thing it came from looked like.

Comment: You cannot do it, because the machine is incomplete. The development of the creature is not uniquely determined by the genome; the environment provided by the egg or by the mother has a major contribution. For example, in many reptiles sex is not genetically determined; whether the embryo becomes a male of a female is determined by the temperature at which the egg is incubated. See [evolutionary developmental biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_developmental_biology). And in many many plants the phenotype is *also* determined by the specific conditions in which the plant grows.

Comment: How is this question about worldbuilding?  Why do you need to know the answer?  Why is "after about thirty minutes a holographic display of the creature appeared" not a suitable solution?

Comment: @JBH To be honest,I don't see why this wouldn't be considering some of my posts in the past have been accepted as worldbuilding. If "why is 'x' not a suitable solution"is a real question we need to be asking I feel like a good quarter of the question on this would be moot. I've asked questions like "Best way for a robot to drink?", "What tests to select for advanced intelligence in wolves?",and most popularly "How deep can I make my underwater facility?"All of these could be explained away in single sentences like "the robots drink" or "the facility is very deep" but I find it more fun to ask.

Comment: I believe you've missed my point.  The examples you provided represent a general technological conditon that represents world-wide conditions.  This is a plot device.  Please explain how the specifics of its operation constitute a rule of your world (and aren't just a plot device) and I'll remove my VTC.

Comment: @JBH I'm sorry, I'm not really understanding why it not being a plot device is a nessessary caveat. Why shouldn't its function be involved in the plot?

Comment: Because according to our [question FAQ](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), plot elements are off-topic.  If you can't explain why this isn't just a plot device (which it almost certainly is), then this is an off-topic question per our rules.

Comment: Let me give you some examples.  "Given the following conditions, would I expect high winds on my world?"  is a worldbuilding question.  "Given the high winds on my world, is it possible to build a wind turbine that can generate 10Mw of power?" might be a worldbuilding question.  "How would you design a wind turbine to generate 10mW of power?" is not a worldbuilding question.

Comment: I agree with JBH: Why do you want an answer to this question? The challenges are going to be overcome via software, which no one will ever see. Are you planning on describing the code to your audience? Regardless, I don't see much worldbuilding involved here.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually harder than you might think.  As it turns out, **DNA doesn't mean anything on its own.** Like all languages, it must be interpreted.  The interpreting hardware is our ribosomes.  They convert the DNA sequence into a series of proteins to be threaded together.  For most lifeforms we care about, this information can be captured in a [DNA Codon Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_codon_table), but that's the end of the easy part.

The hard part is that we just moved from the genome to the proteome.  The behavior of proteins is an open field right now.  It takes substantial computational power to even simulate how proteins would fold.  How they interact is infinitely more complicated.

Finally, you have environmental interactions.  Many structures in the body depend on external stimuli to form.  The most notable that I know of is the [foramen ovale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foramen_ovale_(heart)), which is a hole between the atria of the fetal heart.  As it turns out, it's not very efficient to pump all the blood through the lungs when they are submerged in amniotic fluid.  So all fetuses have a hole which permits a good portion of the blood to simply skip the lungs all together.  When a child is born, the pressure difference caused by the lungs functioning properly triggers this opening to seal itself, which eventually solidifies into the fossa ovalis.  It would be incredibly difficult to identify this without modeling the stresses of breathing in the air.

Which brings us now to the reality that we have to model the entire creature *and* its environment, like a perfect VR simulator at the atomic level.  With the amount of work that would require, you really start to appreciate how living organisms can simply *be*.  They don't have to calculate their way through being.

Now what you could do is build up a database from scratch.  If you started feeding genomes and example creatures into an AI like [AlphaZero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlphaZero), it could start learning the easy to recognize patterns.  It wouldn't be enough to guarantee that you can visualize and simulate any creature from scratch, but my suspicions are that there's a lot of common patterns in our genome, so once you understand those patterns, you can focus on the differences.  It could be enough to give you the rough shape of a reasonable creature, given its DNA.

Comment: Calling DNA a "language" is a gross simplification. Human language has a much higher level of locality, i.e. words have set meanings, with some modifications by local context. The expression of a gene can be modified by another gene anywhere in the genome.

Comment: @Acccumulation I think you'll find that the meaning of words are also affected by genes from elsewhere.  For example, one of the known issues with reading traditional Chinese philosophy is that anyone who read it in those days was also *very* well versed on a great body of what are now called the Chinese Classics.  The meanings of phrases used in that philosophy often referred to those classics, permitting an entire story to be called up with a single sentence.  If you are not versed in those other stories, you miss the meaning of the sentence entirely.

Comment: I also use the term "language" in the formal sense here, as I use the word "interpret."  If it would help, I could go into the meanings of those terms with respect to the mathematics of formal languages, but I found the discussion of proteins and biology more relevant.

Comment: But could it be done on a higher level of abstraction? Where DNA base pairs aren't the words of the language. Like what you're describing is machine language but what the OP is looking for is like Java. One can write programs in Java and not know how they get interpreted into machine language, because someone else has already done that work and provided the framework for it. The main difficulty I see is a lack of knowledge in regard of most of these processes but I can imagine that the future will be better equipped to make software like this.

Comment: @RealSubtle In computer programming, we intentionally create layers of abstraction like this which are designed, from the start, to be understood.  Its generally accepted that genetics was not designed to be understood, it was designed to work.  It is *theoretically* possible that there is some higher level framework, but from a practical perspective, there is zero evidence for it and a great mighty body of evidence against it.  The fundamental issue is that the product created from DNA is proteins, and protein folding is a notoriously non-local process.

Comment: If there was a higher level framework, it would look like the worst spaghetti code you've ever seen written by a 2nd year CS student, aged for 15 years in a low-budget industry, then "upgraded" by a LISP zealot and aged another 10 years maintained by first-year developers micromanaged by a maniacal micromanaging boss from business development or marketing.  At some point in the process, you actually have to start feeling sorry for the poor AI that has to make sense of this mess at the end of all of this!

Comment: Incidentally, this is also the issue we face with modern AIs and optimizing algorithms like Genetic Algorithms.  While they use a language which is capable of creating human-readable algorithms, in practice GAs and AI algorithms rarely find that path.  The algorithms they write tend to be brilliantly effective, but nearly impossible for a human to tease apart and make sense of.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do it.

Example:
http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/11/so-much-abominable-snowman-study-finds-yeti-dna-belongs-bears

DNA was taken from supposed yeti remains.

> Of the nine “yeti” samples, eight turned out to be from bears native
>   to the area, the researchers report today in the Proceedings of the
>   Royal Society B. The other sample came from a dog.

If I can determine from the DNA that the sample was from a female Himalayan brown bear, I can get a pretty good idea of what a female Himalayan brown bear looks like.  As regards the dog DNA, I could probably get a pretty good idea of what a dog from that region looks like too.

You could analyze a tuft of fur found on a fence and determine if it were from a horse, or a dog, or a mountain lion.  You could then have a pretty good idea of what that animal looked like.

The problem would be if you had DNA which you had a hard time matching to any known sequence.  For example you might figure out that something was a cephalopod but lacking any closer matches to determine genus or family, you would have a hard time determining its size or tentacle length.